# Why does waking from hibernate take nearly ten minutes on a Dell XPS 15 L502x laptop?

Tags: power-management, hibernate, xps

Im running 11.10 64bit on a Dell XPS 15 L502x laptop. It uses an i5 proc and has 16Gb ram.

Whenever I close the lid on the laptop I have it set to hibernate as I want to continue whatever I was previously running. Generally that is simple text editing, so my mem usage would normally be only a Gb or 2. When I open the lid and it resumes from Hibernation, it takes up to ten minutes to do so. Extremely frustrating.

Is there anything I can do to make hibernate function properly. On windows it used to wake from Hibernation in less than 30 seconds. Its really frustrating and souring my experience with Ubuntu. Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the uswsusp package. It compresses the data as it writes it out so the process goes faster. 10 minutes seems a bit extreme though, pointing to a more serious hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you hibernate, everything that is stored in your RAM gets copied to your hard disk. When the computer wakes up again, everything is moved back from the hard disk to RAM.

Because you have 16 GB of RAM, that means up to 16 GB must be transferred between your RAM and your hard disk. This naturally takes some time, as hard disks are quite slow.

Comment: Question: but only if there are 16 GB written in RAM.